# DevC++ Error: 'tablero' was not declared in this scope

Tags: c++, clase, dev-c++

Estoy haciendo un ajedrez en C++ y cuando quiero usar la variable tablero en otra funcion fuera del main me tira error. Este es el código:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Tablero.h"

using namespace std;

void ImprimirTablero();

int main()
{
   Tablero<int> tablero;
   ImprimirTablero();
   return 0;
}

void ImprimirTablero()
{
   tablero.MostrarTablero();
}
```

Gracias por la ayuda.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

El problema es que la variable **tablero** estás declarada dentro de la función **main** y por eso no se puede acceder desde la función **ImprimirTablero**, para resolver esto se me ocurren dos opciones:

1) Declarar la variable **tablero** como global:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Tablero.h"

using namespace std;

void ImprimirTablero();

Tablero<int> tablero; // Aquí declaro globalmente a la variable tablero, y puedo usarla desde cualquier función

int main()
{
   ImprimirTablero();
   return 0;
}

void ImprimirTablero()
{
   tablero.MostrarTablero();
}
```

2) Otra opción es pasar la variable como parámetro:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Tablero.h"

using namespace std;

void ImprimirTablero(Tablero<int>& tablero);

int main()
{
   Tablero<int> tablero;
   ImprimirTablero(tablero);
   return 0;
}

void ImprimirTablero(Tablero<int>& tablero)
{
   tablero.MostrarTablero();
}
```

Comment: me  sirvió la primera opción. Gracias por tu ayuda!